# Hello. i want to check delay for my WiFi AP

Tags: networking, wifi, delay

i'm in the master´s course.
in proceeding some projects, my professor advised that you should check the delay about WiFi AP in the connection of 5 stations by sending or receiving packets. 
but i don't specialize in networking, so this drives me crazy how measuring WiFi's delay in the connection of 5 stations.
waiting for your helps.
Thank you. :)

P.S. because i lived in a country whose native language is not english, please understand that there are many errors in grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the IP addresses of those 5 hosts to a file, named **hosts.txt** in my example.

and then run the command bellow:

**for /f "tokens=1" %a in (hosts.txt) DO @ping -n 3 %a**

Then you will get the round-trip delay information.

Regards.

Comment: Ping is a pretty poor choice to check the round-trip delay. It uses ICMP, which is a completely different protocol than what an application would use. ICMP is a low-priority for most network devices, and the ICMP delay can be very different than TCP or UDP.